# How to center the icon I clicked on in the carouselSlider - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

I'm new to Flatter and would love to get some help.
How can I move the icon I clicked to the center?
Is there an understandable way in the widget?

```
    CarouselSlider.builder(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        height: 100.0,
        viewportFraction: 0.3,
        initialPage: trackProvider.currentTrack,
        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
          trackProvider.setCurrentTrackById(widget.sortedTracks[index].id);
          trackProvider.setCurrentPiece(0);
          timer.restartTimer();
          setState(() {
            _currentTrack = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      itemCount: track.tracksDetails.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex, realIndex) {
        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: itemIndex == trackProvider.currentTrack ? 1 : 0.5,
              child: createIconButton(
                trackProvider.tracksDetails[itemIndex]['icon'],
                itemIndex,
                widget.sortedTracks,
                trackProvider,
              ),
            ));
      },
    );
```

[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yui0c.png)

Thanx to you all...